# Confusion about pointer casts in c

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
char* p = (char*) malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(p, "fungus");

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p); i++) {
    printf("%c", p[i]);
}

char* p2 = (char*) malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
*p2 = *(uint16_t*) p;
printf("\nPointer: %c\n", p2[1]);
```

So I created a char* p to store the string "fungus".
To my understanding, if I typecast p to a uint16_t* and dereference it, the returned value should be the first 2 bytes pointed to by p. So, p2[1] should be "u", since "u" is the second byte in the string "fungus". However, this isn't the case when I run my program. I've also tried to print p[0] + 1, but this just outputs "g". Is there an error in my logic?

Comment: Well, besides the fact that strictly spoken you cannot cast a char pointer to any odd type this typically works as expected. Observations: (1) `p[0] + 1` is `'f' + 1`, which *is* 'g'; (2) `*p2 = *(uint16_t*) p` assigns a 16 bit int value to a char (namely `*p2`, which is `p2[0]`), exceeding a char's value range. (3) `p2[1]`, as opposed to what you seem to be thinking, has never been assigned.

Comment: Also consider what the endian is of the system you are working with.  When you cast that char pointer to a unit16 pointer, the bytes could be read in a different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my understanding, if I typecast p to a uint16_t* and dereference it, the returned value should be the first 2 bytes pointed to by p.

This is not correct, for at least two reasons.

One, a pointer to a `char` might not have the alignment required for a `uint16_t`, and then the conversion to `uint16_t` is not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 6.3.2.3 7:

> … If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned70) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…

That will not apply in the example code in the question, since the `char *` is assigned from `malloc`, and `malloc` always returns an address suitably aligned for any fundamental type. However, it may apply to `char *` created in other ways (including by adding offsets to `p`, such as attempting to convert `p+1` to `uint16_t *`).

Two, accessing objects defined as `char` (including those created by writing `char` values to memory allocated with `malloc`) as if they were `uint16_t` violates the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7. It is possible a C implementation might reinterpret the two `char` as a `uint16_t`, but it is also possible that optimization by the compiler might transform the undefined behavior into something else.

> `*p2 = *(uint16_t*) p;`

This code is an assignment to the single char `*p2`, which is `p2[0]`, regardless of the fact that the right-hand side may be a 16-bit value. It does not touch `p2[1]`.

If `*(uint16_t*) p;` does reinterpret two eight-bit bytes of the string as a `uint16_t`, then it will produce some 16-bit value that is then assigned to the single `char` `*p2`. If `char` is unsigned, this will store the low eight bits of that value as `p2[0]`, leaving `p2[1]` untouched. If it is signed, an implementation-defined conversion will be performed, and the result (if a trap does not occur) will be assigned to `p2[0]`, again leaving `p2[1]` untouched.

Then `printf("\nPointer: %c\n", p2[1]);` attempts to print a value that has not been initialized, since nothing has put a value in `p2[1]`.

You could try changing `*p2 = *(uint16_t*) p;` to `* (uint16_t *) p2 = * (uint16_t *) p;` to copy the `uint16_t` whole, instead of trying to cram it into a single byte.